# Single case Discriminated Union in F#, same name for type and label

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I have the following code in an F# file:

```
module ORDERS

type OrderId =           // TypeName
    | OrderId of string  // LabelName: same as TypeName!
    with 
    static member getValue (OrderId orderId) =
        orderId
```

and in another file, I can utilize the function like this:

```
// This code works.
module Application
open ORDERS

let x = OrderId "1111"
let extractedValue = 
    x 
    |> OrderId.getValue
```

However, if I try to remove the "open ORDERS" and replace the code with their full path, I get an error:

```
// This code fails.
module Application

// This is OK
let x2 = ORDERS.OrderId "11111"

// This has error!
let extractValue2 = 
    x2
    |> ORDERS.OrderId.getValue
```

I believe the reason is that in the second code, F# cannot differentiate the TypeName "OrderId", and the LabelName "OrderId"

Question:

1. Why does removing "open ORDERS", but specifying the full path will cause the code to fail? Aren't the two codes (with "open ORDERS"; without "open ORDERS" but specify full name of functions) equivalent?

---

Additional question:

2. Would it be better to rename the TypeName and LabelName differently so that they won't conflict with each other? e.g.

   ```
   module ORDERS
   type OrderIdType =            // TypeName
       | OrderIdLabel of string  // LabelName: different from TypeName!
       with 
       static member getValue (OrderIdLabel orderId) =
           orderId
   ```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This totally looks like a compiler bug. If you alias the type with `type T = ORDERS.OrderId`, then you can use `T.getValue`. I recommend reporting the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, Fyodor Soikin.

Comment: which version of F# and what IDE are you using? I think this is probably an IDE issue.

Comment: I am using F# 4.1. I am using Visual Studio Professtional 15.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this work as shown below by replacing the static method with a module-level getOrderIdValue function instead:

```
module ORDERS =

    type OrderId =           // TypeName
        | OrderId of string  // LabelName: same as TypeName!
        with 
        static member getValue (OrderId orderId) =
            orderId

    let getOrderIdValue (OrderId orderId) =
            orderId

module Application =
    open ORDERS

    let x = OrderId "1111"
    let extractedValue = 
        x 
        |> OrderId.getValue

module ApplicationWithoutOpenOrders =

    // This is OK
    let x2 = ORDERS.OrderId "11111"

    // This has error!
    let extractValue2 = 
        x2
        |> ORDERS.getOrderIdValue
```